# An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (3200000)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Can anyone is facing issue in Manage release in Google play store?
When I try to upload an app in production track. It's not opening. I am getting this error.

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (3200000)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you Uploading with a bundle or apk??

Comment: Not able to upload even

Comment: Same thing is happening with me... Did you find any solution?

Comment: Best sugestion is to contact google support, I tried to google for an answer for you but there is nothing

Comment: It's working now... I just uploaded my application

Comment: It seems like there is some kind of error happening in Google. My app been unable to connect to firebase too, and now I get this same error in play console as well

Comment: For me as well cannot release

Comment: It happens to me also, sometimes it helps if you logout and sign in again. Nonetheless somebody needs to inform google play about this issue..

Comment: Happens to me as well. Support is unable at the moment. Help.

Comment: Same error! I cannot release my app. :(

Comment: In my case, the same error occurs in Safari / Chrome on Mac and Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Same error. I am not able to upload app.

Comment: Did anyone find anything?

Comment: There was the error for 3 hours and could not upload the apk file.
Now I can upload my APK file. I did nothing!

Comment: Even I can upload my apk now.

Comment: I hope it'll help you..: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145712

Comment: I was also facing this issue until the afternoon, now its automatically resolved, now I'm able to upload new apk.

Comment: Now It has started working fine

Answer (score 3):

I had this about 5-6 hours ago then just gave up after seeing no answers. Tried it just now & it works. I guess something was going wrong internally & I just had to wait it out.

Answer (score 2):

[An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (3200000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3LaV.png)

I got this error just now , this error occurs while i need to manage my apk release 
All App release has same error while i need to manage it , i do not know what happened
I do clear browser cache and close all my logged in user

This error still came out of my browser , need some one to help .. please

EDIT :

Hi There who are facing these issue , i just post a question , because i am having this issue as well , but , after i do clear my browser cache , logout all to my google account , close browser windows , and try to clearing all my local cache in from my laptop , wait for at least an hours ,

Now i am able to manage my app on google play store 
Hope this will help others

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I too am having this problem. It seems like a fairly new error code as Google Search only shows a different error code but with the same error message. I've had this happen intermittently for the last 3 to 7 days. Seems like waiting a few hours and trying again works. I also try to sign out, clear my cache, site settings, and cookies before signing it. I am not sure if clearing the web browser is necessary but I do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I used USA proxy and now this error is not coming, everything is working fine.

Maybe Google has pushed some bug in certain countries rollout.

Comment: you used proxy site?

Comment: There was some problem from google's side. Now it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error a while ago. I remember it was this exact error message although I'm not sure about the error code. I still don't know the exact cause of this problem but somehow, **restarting my computer** solved the problem.

Alternatively, I think restarting your browser (rather than your computer) should do the trick. Simply clear your cache, restart and try again.

I hope this helps someone out there.